# selenium showing blank page for local file rendering

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
Ubuntu 20.04
selenium==3.141.0



>>> chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.43 (8c61b7e2989f2990d42f859cac71319137787cce-refs/branch-heads/4515@{#306})
>>> chromium-browser --version
Chromium 92.0.4515.107 snap
>>> chromium --version
Chromium 92.0.4515.107 snap
```

HTML file example.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Rendering html with selenium driver(Passing absolute file path)

```
driver.get('file:///example.html')
```

when checking driver.page_source its showing only

```
'<html><head></head><body></body></html>'
```

Why its loading an empty page ?

there is no specific error for trace back

Note: same code Working fine on on Ubuntu 18

Comment: you mean the `h1` and `p` contents are not displaying right?

Comment: yes nothing is visible even i  tried different HTML files

Comment: are you using chromium browser?

Comment: yes using chromium browser with headless mode the same code is working fine on ubuntu 18

Comment: @YaDavMaNish the issue is only for local files even weburls working fines

Answer (score 0):

So I got the issue instead of using the `file:///example.html`  URL try to provide the absolute path of the page from your local

`file:///Users/userName/Desktop/example.html`

I've checked the way you provided the URL same has displayed for me it is just printing the tag not the content this has worked in my local

[image]

Comment: i already mentioned in question i am passing absolute path for sample purpose i have added that example. as i mention on Ubuntu 18 same code is working

Comment: Can you let me know the OS for which it is not working I have checked in MAC OS

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 , even after call get method i tried to print the current URL and web driver giving current url

Comment: can you check with  abspath("file path") method

Comment: thanks yadav for giving your time after debugging i found the root cause of selenium error on ubunutu. This sounds like an Ubuntu permissions error.  Ubuntu user has execute access, but the user /opt process that is running the selenium don't have that permission